# How to get author of a Notes document using lotus script?

Tags: lotusscript, author

I need to know the user who created the given notes document as well as the user who has last edited it. This is required through Lotus Script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NotesDocument's property [Authors](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/12.0.0/basic/H_AUTHORS_PROPERTY.html).

The first entry of return value is document's creator. The following entries are the users who updated the document. The last entry contains the user who last edited it.